# Delete characters from string according to pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, character

I have a string like URL address:
www.example.com/url-address-link/something-else/last-part/

and patterns:
/url-address-link/{star}/last-part/
or
/url-address-link/{star} .

I need to delete characters from URL address, which are replaced by star in pattern.
Can anybody give me a tip on simplest solution in javascript?

*Note: I already have working solution, but I am sure there is a simpler way, because I have patterns in state I wrote above and I need to automatically transform them into RegExp I wrote below, which is a little bit wild.*

```
string.replace(new RegExp("(\/url-address-link\/)(.+)(\/last-part\/)", "gi"), "$1$3")
```

Comment: Why not just split the url by slashes and join the parts you want back together?

    var parts = "www.example.com/url-address-link/something-else/last-part/".match(/([^\/]+)/g);
    console.log(parts[1] + parts[parts.length - 1]);

Comment: I need to automatize it and at the second pattern above, there is not any last part of string when I split it by slashes. Ideal solution for me would be - find by regular all characters in string which are represented by {star} in pattern and delete them.

Comment: Pattern also could contains more {star} - for example /url/{star}/another/{star}/part/{star} - and in this case woul be little bit complecated with your suggested solution I think.

Comment: Just to be clear: you want to replace "something-else" part with {star} part, where {star} part is something that will be changing dynamically with each page and you have this {star} part as a string variable in your javascript?